# K8: Nginx ingress and serving Javascript files in Symfony app

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

So I have a Symfony application deployed. The app is running, but all my js files throw 404 status code.

When I shell into the pod I can clearly see my `public/build/{files}` present, but the app does not see them. This is my ingress config part:

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    class: nginx-k8s
    servicePortName: tcp
    hosts:
    - host: my-service.service-stg.com
      paths:
      - /*
    auth:
      enabled: false
    additionalAnnotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: myservice.service-stg.com
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: FCGI
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: index.php
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY '';
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT '/var/www/service-web/public';
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME '//var/www/service-web/public/index.php';
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
        location ^~ /build/ {
          alias /var/www/service-web/public/build;
          expires 7d;
        }
```

How do I serve static files, what is missing? Thanks!